# MYSQL - Non deterministic order when using LIMIT and GROUP BY despite using ORDER BY id

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

[image: the db schema]

### Notes about the database

It was generated using Prisma so unfortunately the column names in the many-to-many tables are named "A" and "B". "A" refers to the table which comes first in the alphabet and "B" the second. For example, in _ReadingToWord, "A" refers to Reading.id and "B" refers to Word.id because "r" comes before "w" in the alphabet.

### The problem

I have the below query that uses a limit statement to implement paging.
The problem I am having is that the result order is non-deterministic. (If I execute the query a bunch of times, some of the time the order will be different).

I am ordering by id which is a primary key so I thought that should ensure a consistent order.

Can anyone explain why the ordering is non-deterministic and how to fix it?

```
select * from (
    SELECT w.id,
    hiragana,
    group_concat( distinct(concat(coalesce(r.downStep, -1) + 1 , "," ,r.katakana)) order by r.downStep SEPARATOR ' ') 
    from Hiragana a join _HiraganaToWord b on a.id = b.A join 
    Word w on w.id = b.B join _ReadingToWord rtw on w.id = rtw.B join 
    Reading r on r.id = rtw.A 
    WHERE hiragana like "あ%"
    group by w.id
   ) 
   as groupQuery
 order by length(hiragana), hiragana, id asc limit 600,5;
```

### Sample runs

[image: run 1]
[image: run 2]

Comment: You should include sample data from two runs which explains the non deterministic ordering problem.  The solution is most likely to add more things to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the reply, I have now added some sample runs that shows the issue. If I am already ordering by id, which is a primary key and therefore unique, why might adding more columns to the ORDER BY clause help?

Comment: Your query is returning different results on some runs: the first sample has `id=47348` and the second has `id=31752`. Other than that difference the sorting on `id` is identical: `42423<51567<77656<49498`; presumably the reason the sort on `id` is not strictly ascending is because of the `length(hiragana), hiragana` you have in the `order by` clause

Comment: Your query is malformed.  The `SELECT` columns are not consistent with the `GROUP BY`.  No doubt, that is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing one of the subtle side-effects of disabling [`only_full_group_by`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html):

> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. **In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic**, which is probably not what you want.

If you would enable that mode, you would get an error like

> Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'a.hiragana' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

and searching on stackoverflow for that error message will give you lots and lots of examples for this problem.

So in your query

```
SELECT w.id, a.hiragana, 
...
group by w.id
...
order by hiragana
```

the values for `hiragana` are not necessarily deterministic. If, for the same `w.id`, there are several values for `a.hiragana`, MySQL can pick any of those. And if you order by that non-deterministically chosen value, you can get different orders. MySQL doesn't actually pick a random row, just doesn't care which one it is, so oftentimes, you get the same (which can make this harder to spot), but not always.

It doesn't have to be the entry with id 31752 for which MySQL has picked a different value for `hiragana` (it can be any of the previous 600 rows), but I would check that value first - if it has a 2nd value that also starts with "あ" but would be ordered after the value for 47348 (or is longer), it might immediately make things clearer.

You can technically fix this by picking a deterministic value there, e.g. the min or max value:

```
select * from (
   SELECT w.id,
   min(hiragana) as hiragana, 
   ...
   group by w.id
   ) as groupQuery
order by length(hiragana), hiragana, id asc limit 600,5;
```

You have to check if that is what you are actually trying to do (e.g., if there are several choices for `hiragana`, you don't care which one is chosen, as long as it is a determinic one) and if this fits your required result. Other choices might be `group by w.id, a.hiragana` or `group by w.id, a.id`, or maybe you need to completely rewrite your query (as it may not cover this case).

Comment: Thank you! I would have never of realised this by myself..
It looks like AWS has this option off by default. Now I've turned it on I am getting the error!